# How to use dedicated graphics card on Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, cpu

I want to use my dedicated AMD cart that is built into my computer, but whenever I run a game on my laptop, it says that the graphics processor is the on-board Intel-graphics processor. I have checked the Catalyst center and have selected the games to run on High-Performance, but that doesn't work. The only way I can think of is to disable it in the Control Panel, and update the Drivers of the AMD card, but this also doesn't work, as when I want to view the Catalyst Centre, it opens momentarily and closes soon after. Any ideas on how to switch to a dedicated card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have most likely plugged your monitor into your onboard(motherboard) graphics.

To utilize your gpu your monitor must be plugged into the gpu you wish to use.

Comment: I would not have thought of that. Thats a good point. I will have a look into that